# Customizing LdapUserDetails in Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I am building a Spring Boot app with Spring Security that is using ldap for authentication. I am trying to add a Person object to a custom LdapUserDetails object that can be accessed from a controller, but am having trouble calling that custom LdapUserDetails object.

My implementation of LdapUserDetails is below:

```
public class DirXUserDetails implements LdapUserDetails {
private final Person user;

public DirXUserDetails(Person user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Person.SecurityRole[] roles = user.getRole();
    if (roles == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return Arrays.<GrantedAuthority>asList(roles);
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return user.getUserId();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

public Person getUser() {
    return user;
}


@Override
public String getDn() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Here is my UserDetailsServiceImpl class:

```
@Component
public class DirXUserDetailsImpl implements DirXUserDetailsService {

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DirXUserDetailsImpl.class.getName());

@Autowired
private PersonService personRepository;

@Autowired
private Session session;

@Override
public DirXUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    log.info("Load user: " + userId);

    final Person user = personRepository.findByUserId(userId);

    if(user == null) {
        log.info("Username not found: " + userId);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + userId);
    }

    return new DirXUserDetails(user);
}
```

Here is my implementation of UserDetailsService:

```
public interface DirXUserDetailsService extends UserDetailsService {


@Override
public DirXUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException;

Person getUserFromSession();
}
```

And finally the controller:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName());

@Autowired
PersonService personService;

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView dashboard(Authentication authentication) {

    DirXUserDetails dirXUserDetails = (DirXUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("dashboard");
    mav.addObject("user", dirXUserDetails.getUser());
    return mav;
}
}
```

This error comes when calling `DirXUserDetails dirXUserDetails = (DirXUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl cannot be cast to org.directoryx.service.DirXUserDetails
at org.directoryx.web.HomeController.dashboard(HomeController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:799) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:728) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

After debugging I see that `loadUserByUsername()` is being called in DirXUserDetailsImpl and DirXUserDetails is being returned to Spring Security, but when trying to call `authentication.getPrincipal()` in the controller it returns an LdapUserDetailsImpl object and not a DirXUserDetails object.

I have looked at the Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE docs as well as many other Spring Security articles but couldn't find anything on this. How can I access DirXUserDetails from the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was going about this the wrong way. The UserDetailsService used is not what Spring Security's LdapAuthenticationProvider uses to create the UserDetails, it is actually an implementation of an LdapUserDetailsMapper. The following code solved my issue:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

@Override
public CustomUserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations dirContextOperations, String userId, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
    return new CustomUserDetails();
}
}
```

And set the UserDetailsMapper in the Spring Security Config file like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomUserDetailsMapper userDetailsMapper;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.
                ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("cn={0}").userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsMapper)
                .contextSource(contextSource())
}
```